# how to plot timestamp(milliseconds) in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have text file with datas as follows:

```
0   0:00:01.192000
1   0:00:00.977000
2   0:00:00.955000
3   0:00:00.959000
4   0:00:00.948000
5   0:00:00.934000
```

And the python code as :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('TR.txt') as f:
lines = f.readlines()

y = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]
x = [line.split()[1] for line in lines]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("SMP graph")
ax1.set_xlabel('hour')
ax1.set_ylabel('smp')
ax1.bar(x,y, width=0.7)

fig1=plt.gcf()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
```

But the code throw an error because of floating in the milliseconds.

Note: I would like to draw the plot as column 0 in x axis & column 1 in Y axis.

Please any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should not through any error in matplotlib 2.1 or higher. But the plot will not be useful at all. You would want to convert your first data to integer, the second one to datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer you the following solution using pandas:

Read the data, note that the separator has two spaces.

```
lines = pd.read_csv('TR.txt', sep="  ", header=None, engine='python')
```

Give the dataframe columns names. Column_1 is your time column.

```
lines.columns = ['column_0', 'column_1']
```

I tried various options to parse your timestamp more elegantly, but without success. However, I think you can still plot seconds using decimal and get a useful graph. Therefore, I changed the format of the timestamp and converted the result to float.

```
lines['column_1'] = lines['column_1'].str[6:].astype('float')
```

Then you graph:

```
lines.plot(x='column_0')
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  when I run the above code, I could see below ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 element.

Comment: Does your data exactly look like in your sample? Does it have a header line? In what type of file is your data stored (.txt, ...) ?

Comment: Format is text file & no header is available as well. I have written data in text file using below command: text_file.write(str(i)+'\t'+str(response.elapsed)+'\n') where i denotes the iteration.

Comment: Ah ok, I think your problem is caused by the tab character '\t' and new line character '\n'. I have no means of testing it, but can you try the following way to write your data: `text_file.write(str(i)+','+str(response.elapsed)\n')` The tab character is replaced by a ',' and the new line character is directly placed after the string.

Then in the line, where we read the data, the separator needs to be changed to comma:
lines = pd.read_csv('TR.txt', sep=",", header=None, engine='python')
Please let me know if it worked.